# If i put wrong password then also form is logged in? how could i solve this issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sign up page works fine but log in page password not correct then also form is logged in..pls help

This is my users.controller.rb which has new and create action

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  end

  def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/users/index', :notice => 'Signed In!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password,  :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

This is my sessions.controller.rb which has new,create and destroy

```
def new
  end
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email],[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id]= user.id
      redirect_to '/users/index', :notice => 'Logged In'
    else
      flash.now.alert = 'Invalid email or Password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id]= nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Logged Out'
  end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  private
  def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

This is my new.html.erb for users controller-Sign Up Page

```
      <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div class = "error_messages">
           <h2>Form is Invalid</h2>
          <ul>
            <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
                <li> <%= message %> </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :password %> <br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %> <br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </p>
<p class = button> <%= f.submit %> </p>
<% end %>
```

This is my new.html.erb for sessions controller(Log In Page)

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
    <p>
<%= label_tag :email %> <br />
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
</p>
    <p>
      <%= label_tag :password %> <br />
      <%= password_field_tag :password,params[:password] %>
    </p>
<p class=> <%= submit_tag %> </p>
<% end %>
```

This is User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password


  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate (email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Comment: no i am not using devise

Comment: Add your `User` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen into the classic "single equals vs double equals trap"

```
if user && user.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
```

should be

```
if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You compared password with single equal sign (`=`), which is not comparing rather assigning. So the condition returning `true` always.

Change your `authenticate` action into this:

```
def self.authenticate (email, password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  hashed_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)

  if user && user.password_hash == hashed_password
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

And you have typo in the following line in your Session Controller's `create` action:

```
user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
```

Comment: Again the same problem is coming

Comment: Post your `User` model, need to see the implementation of `authenticate` action.